# How to measure Speed of moving vehicle?

Tags: android

I am new to android and i am trying to make a application in android that measure the speed of an moving car in which that device is placed ?
Please help me

Comment: I haven't done this before but I guess you'd have to use location/gps service to locate your position at time A and time B and use that to calculate the speed.

Comment: Like [Speed Meter](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Speed%20meter) ?

Comment: any code example ??
i have done this and get position but i can't find speed
if u allow i will send u my code please see it and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. Its helps you

```
LocationManager lm;
Location location;
lm = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
location.getBearing();//speed
```

Add permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> –
```

Comment: Also mentioned for necessary permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: Obviously I know this. I am saying to add this in your answer to make it perfect answer.

Comment: Please anyone give me a complete code example i am new to android

Comment: write the above code in your event listener. You'll get the speed.

Comment: Speed always show value 0??

Answer (score 0):

If you ask your device for it's location periodically, you can then estimate average speed by `locationDelta / timeDelta`.

The `locationDelta` is length of a vector from position A to B and `timeDelta` is a time(whenLocationB)-time(whenLocationA).

Google for how to get current location in android, and how to run code periodically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getSpeed() method of Location class.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed%28%29)